# iTunes Connect SUBMIT button won't work

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ios10, appstore-approval

Basically I tap the submit button it spins and then goes back to the default state. I can't submit app...

I added eBay EPN stuff but that was the same as last build. + checking that I do have ads on the bottom (if that was the thing I'm getting auto-stopped by) did noting and the button still would not go. :(

How do I get this to work so I can submit my build...?

[image: This is after you upload all the correct app info and binary and hit the submit button on the prior main console page]

Comment: Looks normal.. Tried restarting your computer and trying again? It always blows my mind what the source of such errors can be.. It just might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's hard to say what's exact problem,try below steps

1. Major thing is make sure you are using `Safari browser` for iTunes
   connect process.It quite better than all others.
2. Sign out your iTunes connect account & try again the process.if possible then add new version of app.

If still you have the problem then no way **Contact iTunes support team**.

Comment: Came back 24hrs later and opened same iTunes Connect tab. Itunes Connect signed me out automatically and I authenticated again (through the iTunes Connect portal not the Dev. Console) When I went to submit it spun a long time, then showed the error but still completed its process and submitted my app!